# Is there any limitation of JSON data size with HTTP Protocol?

Tags: json, http

I need to separate Server/Client(now it is one, but have to divided) Program.

So Here is my plan

- server : queries to database. send data as type of JSON.
- client : receives json data from server.

The thing I worry about is data size. I expect server will send data which almost sizes 200MB. Is it proper size to transfer with http protocol? or should I make this as a file and send via FTP?(but I expect that client will not open extra port for this :<)

P.S 
Is there any reference what is the proper size of json data? 
Thanks ahead.

Comment: I mistake. its size is 2MB when I watch in chrome inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit for the amount of data that can be transmitted over HTTP. HTTP also doesn't care what kind of data you are sending/receiving. It can be audio, video or JSON, so you should be safe.

Moreover, HTTP servers and clients can easily use gzip to make the requests/response more compact, and since JSON is text based, the content can be compressed quite a lot.

In short, there is no problem with your approach.